# How to sort rows based on a column that contains array values (PHP/MySQL/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

First i should say that I'm looking for a solution with php/mysql and JS/jQuery, but i don't know what would be the best general approach for larger datasets (40.000+).

Imagine you have a database and would like to make it possible to sort the table based on a column with cells that contain arrays. For example, one person can have multiple professions, e. g.

```
Person A - [actor, screenwriter, director]
Person B - [premier minister, president, actor]
```

So imagine since there are a lot of different professions and a large percentage of persons have multiple of them, so the professions of each person are stored in an array, how else would you store them, right?

So i was thinking I'm going to collect all persons with all their profession-arrays and remove duplicates to end up with a list of all possible professions, then create a table out of these and give an ID to each of these professions, and then assign these back to the persons that have the corresponding professions, so i end up with something like

```
id 1 - actor
id 2 - screenwriter
id 3 - director
id 4 - premier minister
id 5 - president
...
```

and in the persons table, in the professions column:

```
Person A - [1, 2, 3]
Person B - [4, 5, 1]
```

So of course i could just create a search bar for the column or filter checkboxes to filter by profession to find all actors, all presidents etc. by providing a checkbox for each profession.

But: even if i was to sort each single array in ascending order to be displayed for the user to see ah, here's all the actors, because the first word you'd see in each cell of the professions-column over the first few pages of the results would look somewhat fine, e.g.

```
Person A - [(a)ctor, (d)irector, (s)creenwriter]
Person C - [(a)ctor, (p)remier minister, (p)resident]
...
```

But what happens when you move on further pages? When you get to the professions starting with D you won't find those persons that have ANY profession that starts with "A" because they have already been displayed under "A" because we sorted the table in ascending order.

What about something like this:

now if you would like to sort these persons ascending by profession and you would want to end up with a list like this:

```
Person A - (a)ctor
Person B - (a)ctor
Person C - (a)ctor
...
Person A - (d)irector
Person D - (d)irector
...
Person B - (p)remier minister
Person E - (p)remier minister
...
```

so that the entries get "duplicated" to be displayed later on when they also have a profession starting with "D" under "D".

I really hope I explained this well enough, if not please ask!

I'd be happy about your suggestions on what to look into on this, examples of code, suggestions on how to apporach this the best way. I want to learn it. Maybe you would even recommend a totally different approach and not work with sorting so much but rather with getting the filtering and searching, because maybe there is just a limit to this idea of sorting/displaying entries mechanism.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: *how else would you store them, right?* Study many-to-many relation. This info must be stored in separate adjacency table.

Comment: Thank you , i haven't worked with n:m relations yet. Will look into that. Anything more to add to this?

Answer (score 0):

Recommended structure:

Persons table:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    person_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    person_name VARCHAR(255),
    -- another columns related to person
    );
```

Professions table:

```
CREATE TABLE Profession (
    profession_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    profession_name VARCHAR(255),
    -- another columns related to profession
    );
```

Adjacency table:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonToProfession (
    person_id INT NOT NULL,
    profession_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id, profession_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES Person (person_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (profession_id) REFERENCES Profession (profession_id)
    );
```

On this structure the query is simple:

```
-- show all persons with lexically first profession
SELECT person_name, 
       ( SELECT profession_name 
         FROM Profession pr
         JOIN PersonToProfession ptp USING (profession_id)
         WHERE pe.person_id = ptp.person_id
         ORDER BY pr.profession_name ASC LIMIT 1 ) profession_name 
FROM Person pe
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/8yZR96iK)

Comment: Thank you again, Akina, i will work my way through it and come back to you on this.

Comment: I understand, so one table just for the individual person, one for every possible profession, and the adjacency table that holds each single relation individually, so if a person has only one profession, that person appears only once in the adjacency table, if two twice, if three three times and so on. What do i have to select in order to have all the other professions one person has shown behind the profession (ACTOR, director, screenwriter), and later that person is shown under "D" as (DIRECTOR, actor, screenwriter) and so on?

Comment: I'm searching for this everywhere and can't find anything about it. so in each row the person appears, i'd like to still show the lexically second profession of that person behind the lexically first profession, and later on when the lexically second profession of that person is shown first, i'd like to still show the lexically first profession behind it, so that you always see the current lexical profession first, but also the other professions of that person behind it.

Comment: @stst *What do i have to select in order to have all the other professions one person has shown behind the profession (ACTOR, director, screenwriter),* ```.. ORDER BY profession = 'actor' DESC, ..```

Comment: Been trying to figure out what you mean for an hour now and I'm getting errors only, if you could update your demo i can accept your answer and mark it as solved. Maybe It would be easier to make a server side pagination and just get the persons with all professions and later on let the php code handle the custom sorting depending on where you're at lexically.

Comment: @stst https://dbfiddle.uk/csN5w6rh

Comment: With this, the other professions are still not displayed, I still get only the "current" profession..